# Uploading to SharePoint with TFS

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I'm trying to upload the Output of my Build Process to the SharePoint-Website but don't find a solution.

My Problem is that my build don't create "Standard" Output. It is a custom process which basically just executes a program on the build Server through cmd. This program generates a file which I would like to upload. Because it isn't Standard Output the drop Folder functionallity is not working and thats why I Need a different way to upload this file to the SharePoint-Website.
Driver mapping, through cmd and custom activity programming is no Option here :/

Is there a way to say that this file is my Output? If yes could I just say that my drop Location is the SharePoint Server?

Using VS and TFS 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can manually upload document to the SharePoint site:

[image]

Or you could create an Activity that uses SharePoint API to publish the output to SharePoint Server as SharePoint has its own API/SDK to upload files/folders to server.